# Why .forEach is returning undefined once called in my controller in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, foreach

I have an array movies that holds objects and each object has a property called avgRating with a float or integer number. Example:

```
const movies = [
  {
    name: 'Rambo I', avgRating: 4.6659
  },
  {
    name: 'Rambo II', avgRating: 3.158
  },
  {
    name: 'Rambo III', avgRating: 3.956
  }
];
```

Inside the util.js file I have a function to round the avgRatings of each movie inside the closest 0.5 or integer:

```
exports.roundingAvgRating =  (movies) => {
  const moviesCopy = [...movies];
  return moviesCopy.forEach((movie) => {
    if (movie.avgRating === null) {
      movie.avgRating = null
    } else {
      movie.avgRating = Math.round(movie.avgRating * 2) / 2;
    }
  });
};
```

The problem is that when I call the function in my controller, it returns undefined.

```
const { roundingAvgRating } = require('../utils/roundingAvgRatings.js');
const roundedRatings = roundingAvgRating(searchItems)
console.log(roundedRatings) // undefined...why?
```

Comment: forEach will not return anything

Comment: What did you expect it to return?

Comment: Because [`forEach`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) **always** returns `undefined`.

Comment: I expected that when this is run const roundedRatings = roundingAvgRating(searchItems), then roundedRatings  should be the array with the rounded avgRatings

Comment: @Lomono - Sounds like you wanted [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `(movies) => movies.map(({avgRating}) => avgRating === null ? null : Math.round(avgRating * 2) / 2);`

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to map your movies, and you should return movie each time in loop. like this:

```
const movies = [
  {
    name: 'Rambo I', avgRating: 4.6659
  },
  {
    name: 'Rambo II', avgRating: 3.158
  },
  {
    name: 'Rambo III', avgRating: 3.956
  }
];

const roundingAvgRating = (movies) => {
  

  return movies.map((movie) => {
    if (movie.avgRating) {
       movie.avgRating = Math.round(movie.avgRating * 2) / 2;
    }
    return movie
  });
}
```

also you don't need to make copy in map

Answer (score 3):

```
return movies.map((movie) => {
  if (movie.avgRating) {
     movie.avgRating = Math.round(movie.avgRating * 2) / 2;
  }
  return movie;
});
```